# Photo Editing Extension iOS 8: enable my app to use extension of another app

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, ios8-extension

I've an app which can takes pictures from camera or library.
I found many tutorials of "how to create a Photo Editing Extension"... But here, I don't want to create an extension, but access, from my app, to an extension to customize a picture imported in my app.

So, for example:

- AppName1 has a Photo Editing Extension. I've installed it on my iPhone.
- I launch my app (mine), choose a picture from my library or take one from my camera.
- Now I've my photo, I would like open this photo with the extension of "AppName1", do some stuff, and finally, save the modifications and go back to my app.

Is it possible to do this ? Thank you for your help, I hope my explanation is clear ;)

Best regards,

Comment: by reading this blog i found that you jsut need to add share button like we add before for "Open in" and iOS will show you the available extensions. http://www.howtogeek.com/197150/how-to-use-app-extensions-on-an-iphone-or-ipad-with-ios-8/

Comment: I think I've already try this... Maybe I forgot something... I will try again and stay you tuned ;) Thanks ;)